# Excel: in 2 page view, horizontal scrolling disabled

Tags: copy-paste, excel-2013

Excel 2013: in 2 page view, horizontal scrolling does not work in page 2.  Copying a cell contents from page one to page 2 for instance, using = (equal), and pasting to page 2, cannot scroll horizontally.

I have not made any "tries", not knowing what I can do to fix the problem.